# Get Values between Each Comma in Seperate Row in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I need to insert multiple rows in a database table from a single string.

Here is my string it will be comma-seperated values

Current string:

```
batch 1 45665 987655,1228857 76554738,12390 8885858,301297 38998798
```

What I want is that batch 1 should be ignored or removed and remaining part should be added into the SQL Server database as a separate row for after each comma like this

Table name `dbo.MSISDNData`

```
Data
------------------
45665 987655
1228857 76554738
12390 8885858
301297 38998798
```

and when I query the table it should return the results like this

Query :

```
Select data 
from dbo.MSISDNData
```

Results

```
Data
---------------------
45665 987655
1228857 76554738
12390 8885858
301297 38998798
```

Comment: For latest versions see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @Data NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'batch 1 45665 987655,1228857 76554738,12390 8885858,301297 38998798'
DECLARE @DataXML XML;

SET @Data = '<a>' + REPLACE(REPLACE(@Data, 'batch 1 ', ''), ',', '</a><a>') + '</a>';
SET @DataXML = @Data;

SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(T.c.value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'))) AS [Data]
FROM @DataXML.nodes('./a') T(c);
```

It demonstrates how to split the data. You may need to sanitize it, too - remove the `batch 1`, perform trimming, etc.

Comment: wow thank you so much gotqn , it works like charm. data is perfectly formatted just as i wished. thanks agains